# Safely iterate over a std::vector while items may be erased

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, iterator

There is a global event manager in my application. Every component can listen to events and trigger them. Let's take a look at the window component. It holds a `std::vector` of windows, which it iterates over on a regular basis to handle input and so on. Moreover, it registers to the `"keydown"` event to remove the active window when the escape key is pressed.

```
class window : public module {
    window() {
        // Listen to key event
        listen("keydown", [=](size_t index, int code) {
            if (code == 27) {
                windows[index].close();
                windows.erase(windows.begin() + index);
            }
        });
    }

    void update() {
        for (auto i = windows.begin(); i != windows.end(); i++) {
            if (i->is_open()) // On remove, crashes at this line.
                // ...
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is that when the `"keydown"` event is triggered, either from inside the update loop or from another thread, the code crashes. I guess this is because the iterator isn't valid anymore after erasing an element. Without knowing when the erase happens, how can I safely iterate over the changing vector?

The error says that `i` cannot be dereferenced. I tried wrapping the loop body by a try catch block, but there is no exception to catch, just a debug assertion from Visual Studio.

Comment: What do you expect any of `i`, `windows.begin()` or `windows.end()` to point to if the vector got relocated? I think you need to rethink your design.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier So I'll need a level of indirection. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Without knowing when the erase happens, how can I safely iterate over the changing vector?

You can't.

It is undefined behaviour to access a `std::vector` (or any other standard container) while it is being modified by another thread.

You need to ensure that the thread modifying the vector prevents any other thread from accessing it concurrently, e.g. by using a mutex.

In C++14 you could use a `std::shared_timed_mutex` to protect the vector, so that threads that only need to read from the vector can take a shared lock, but the thread that wants to modify the vector can take an exclusive lock while it makes the changes.

```
class window : public module {
    std::shared_timed_mutex m_mutex;

    window() {
        // Listen to key event
        listen("keydown", [=](size_t index, int code) {
            if (code == 27) {
                std::unique_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> lock(m_mutex);
                windows[index].close();
                windows.erase(windows.begin() + index);
            }
        });
    }

    void update() {
        std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        for (auto i = windows.begin(); i != windows.end(); i++) {
            if (i->is_open())
                // ...
        }
    }
};
```

(N.B. I changed `i.is_open()` to `i->is_open()` as I assume that's what you really have in your code.)

This will only help when the changes are done by another thread, it will deadlock if the keydown event is triggered by the update loop.

Another solution is to postpone removing items from the vector and periodically clean up "dead" items. You still need a mutex to prevent concurrent accesses while modifying the vector, but can avoid deadlock by only holding the lock for a small section of code. Something like:

```
class window : public module {
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::vector<size_t> m_expired;

    window() {
        // Listen to key event
        listen("keydown", [=](size_t index, int code) {
            if (code == 27) {
                windows[index].close();
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
                m_expired.push_back(index);
            }
        });
    }

    void update() {
        erase_expired();
        for (auto i = windows.begin(); i != windows.end(); i++) {
            if (i->is_open())
                // ...
        }
    }

    void erase_expired()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        std::sort(m_expired.begin(), m_expired.end(), std::greater<>{});
        for (auto idx : m_expired)
            windows.erase(windows.begin() + idx);
        m_expired.clear();
    }
};
```

Comment: What if the update loop triggers the keydown event? I think this would cause a dead lock.

Comment: Is there something that would act as recursive shared timed mutex?

Comment: @danijar. Yes, it would deadlock. If that can happen you should consider leaving the element in the vector but maybe adding it to a list of elements to be removed, then periodically remove all expired elements when nothing else is accessing the vector.

Comment: @RafalMielniczuk, no. Recursive mutexes are usually a hack to work around a bad design, not a solution.

Comment: In my real code, not only the events but also the vector is managed globally. The manager provides begin and end iterators and functions for inserting, random access and deletion. Therefore, it would be easy to add a mutex and append items to be removed to a list. However, since the manager doesn't get updated regularly, how does it know when to apply the removes?

Comment: You can call `erase_expired` from other code too, that's why I made it a separate function. But does it really matter if they don't get removed until later?

Comment: It's perfectly fine if they get removed later. I launch a thread that waked up every couple of milliseconds and checks for expired elements. What currently bothers me more is the deadlock. Do you have an idea to overcome this in an elegant way?

Comment: Why would the `erase_expired()` version deadlock?